# why is Object.keys show id as key?

Tags: javascript

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click">
```

JS

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
console.log(Object.keys(a));
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(a).length; i++) {
    console.log(a[i]);
}
```

in console there are three keys is showing 0,1,'btn' . why is id showing in this object and how can i avoid this .

Comment: `var a = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
[].forEach.call(a, function(el) {
  console.log(el)
})` - will do... no.. you can't hide that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a collection from `getElementsByTagName()` you can refer to an item either by its index or its ID.

So `a[0]` or `a.btn`.

I suspect you just want to iterate over all of them, which is just your basic `for` loop from Programming 101:

```
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    // a[i]
}
```

That's what `.length` is there for!